How to disable scroll animation intellij so that it jumps
I noticed that the Intellij scrolling behaviour is incredibly slow. I wanted to disable the animaton so that it just "jumps" in code a given line.
I tried disabling scrolling in Tools>Diagrams, it did not seem to work however.

Try disabling the following options:


For diagrams, you can also disable their animation here:

